# How to create CSS for an existing web application that now is used in a Kiosk with touch screen

Tags: php, jquery, css, user-interface, touch

i have to adapt an existing web application for use in a kiosk that provides only a touch screen. The application is based on php-jquery and i have to diversificate some html elements (created by php) and CSS for the touch screen interface.

How can i do that?Is there some specific directive in CSS for touch screen? (i'm not talking about mobile screens, the kiosk will have a normal resolution). Is there a way to make the php know that the user is using the touch screen (so that i can change html accordingly)?

And, last but not least, are there any consolidated best practices/guidelines for deveolping touch screen interfaces?

Thx in advance, hope this is not a duplicate of another question

Comment: I think you shouldn't be adjusting your code. Let the touchscreen adjust the results!

Comment: I just need to adjust the html layout of the screen. Maybe is should take that part out of php

Comment: maybe this link can help you: http://alastairc.ac/2010/03/detecting-touch-based-browsing/

Comment: Which browser is used on the Kiosk system?

Comment: I think we can choose the browser. Do you have one to suggest?

Comment: Sorry, lost track of this question. I have to agree with NimmoNet, Opera with the projection media is probably the best fit. Maybe also contact the browser makers for possibilies to create/modifiy browsers for your needs. Also there is Mozillas XULRunner, which may be usable.

Comment: you still using php as kiosk ? May I know how u make it full screen in kiosk?coz I press 11, then after a click/action...it shows address bar again?any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a media type defined for kiosk type devices in the [css spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html).  The closest is probably tv, but the kiosk browser will proably load the screen type anyway.

Could you detect the browser the kiosks are using and return a different style sheet?

Comment: That was my first idea, but i thought it wasn't exactly the best...what if the same browser is used by a home user?Any way thx for the link!

Comment: This is nasty but you could check to see if browser is running fullscreen by checking screen.width x screen.height == screen.availWidth x screen.availHeight

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your browser run on the Kiosks... for example if your running Opera they treats full screen as a different CSS media type. They call it Opera Show, and you can control it yourself easily:

@media projection {
  /* these rules only apply in full screen mode */
}

As a kiosk is normally run in full screen mode this would work for you.